# New List made by calling `oldList.copy()` still references the old list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I desire to create a copy of a list to perform some calculations, without affecting the original list. However, my code creates a named reference to the original list. Any changes I make to the new list are also applied to the old list. What am I doing wrong here?

```py
tri = [[1],
    [2,8],
    [9,1,2]]

def tempR():
    ''' add up resulting triangle from RIGHT move '''
    # Generate triangle
    tempTri = tri.copy()
    del(tempTri[0])
    for r in range(len(tempTri)):
        del(tempTri[r][0])

    # Sum all the values
    pValue = 0
    for r in range(len(tempTri)):
        for d in tempTri[r]:
            pValue += d
    return(pValue)

tempR()
print(tri)
```

```
[[1], [8], [1, 2]]
```

I have tried both `tempTri = list(tri)` and `tempTri = tri.copy()` as suggested [in this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list/2612815).

What am I missing?

Comment: Use `copy.deepcopy`

Comment: The marked duplicate answer provides a great answer and solution. Thank you @Stephan_Rauch for the reference.